# stringstream: taking multiple ints in a string and returning those to vector

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am taking a string and using stringstream to pull out the ints in the string and then push those into a vector. My problem is doing this when I don't necessarily know the exact number of ints in the string. The string could be "23,45,68" or it could be "-1,10,15,-22,199,12". My code is below:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<int> parseInts(string str) {
    vector<int>v; 
    char ch;
    int a,b,c;
    stringstream s(str);
    s >> a >> ch >> b >> ch >> c;
    v.push_back(a);
    v.push_back(b);
    v.push_back(c);
    return v;
}

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    vector<int> integers = parseInts(str);
    for(int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
        cout << integers[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a `while` loop to read into a temporary `int` variable, and push that into the `vector` each time. The stream converts to `false` after a failed read operation (i.e. it ran out of things to read), so you can use that as the loop condition. You probably need to use [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline#Example) to read from `cin` in the first place though, as `>>` will stop on the first whitespace, so just read the first `int`.

Comment: @BoBTFish That looks like a decent answer. Are you going to create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the while loop was ending when it hit the "," in the string. In the loop I added code to drop the comma into a char holder "ch" This resolved the problem:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<int> parseInts(string str) {
    //cout << "str is " << str;
    vector<int>v;
    int x;
    char ch;
    stringstream num(str);
    while (num >> x)
    {
        num >>ch;   
        v.push_back(x); 
    }
    return v;
}

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    vector<int> integers = parseInts(str);
    for(int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
        cout << integers[i] << "\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```